# CSS sprites not aligning with text

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am trying to create a website that has a user navigation bar at the top of the web page. However, I am unable to get the sprites, "profile-in" and "arrow" to align with the text "Alfred the Awful". I think that is something missing from my CSS style sheet code, but I cannot seem to figure out which part of the CSS style sheet is wrong.

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could help me look at this.

Thanks!

```css
* {
   font-family: sans-serif;
   font-size: 16px;
}

*, html {
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
   height: 50px;
   border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
   background-color: #F1F1F1;
}

header h1 {
   font-size: 1.5em;
   font-weight: bold;
   margin-left: 50px;
   line-height: 50px;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
   font size: 100%;
   font-weight: normal;
}

h2 {
   display: block;
   font size: 1.5em;
   font-weight: bold;
}

div {
   display: block;
}

.message {
   margin-left: 50px;
}

.select_users {
   position: absolute;
   right: 65px;
   top: 15px;
}

.profile-out, .profile-in, .arrow {
   display: inline-block;
}

.select_users h2 a {
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 0.9em;
   color: black;
   text-decoration: none;
}

.select_users h2 a:hover {
   color: #A32824;
}

ul.users_menu, ul.admin_menu {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    background-color: #F1F1F1;
}

ul.users_menu {
   width: 200px;
}

ul.admin_menu {
   width: 150px;
   display: none;
}

ul.users_menu a, ul.admin_menu a {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: black;
} 

.users_menu li a, .admin_menu li a  {
   font-size: 0.75em;
   padding: 5px;
   display: block;
}

ul.users_menu li a:hover, .admin_menu li a:hover {
   background-color: #A32824;
   color: white;
}

ul.users_menu li.logout {
   border-top: 1px solid grey;
   text-transform: uppercase;
}

ul.users_menu li.logout a {
   background-color: white;
   color: black;
}

ul.users_menu li.logout a:hover {
   background-color: black;
   color: white;
}

.admin_users, .admin_movies {
   margin-top: 40px;
   margin-left: 50px;
}

.admin_users h2, .admin_movies h2 {
   font-size: 1.25em;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.admin_table {
   border-spacing: 2px;
   border-collapse: separate;
}

.admin_table th {
   font-weight: bold;
   text-align: left;
   background-color: #F1F1F1;
}

.admin_table th, .admin_table td, .admin_table input {
   height: 35px;
   width: 200px;
}

th.admin_col, td.deletecell, td.insertcell {
   width: 80px;
}

.admin_table th, .admin_table input {
   padding-left: 5px;
   padding-right: 5px;
}

.admin_table input {
   font-size: 0.9em;
}

.admin_table input:focus {
   background-color: #FEE5AC;
}

.admin_table th, .admin_table td {
   border: 1px solid black;
}

input {
   outline: none;
   border: none;
}

input::-ms-clear {
   display: none;
}

.favs_list {
    float: left;
    width: 175px;
    margin-left: 45px;
}

.favs_list h2 {
   font-size: 0.8em;
   font-weight: bold;
   margin-top: 20px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   margin-left: 5px;
}


ul.favs {
    width: 170px;
    
}

ul.favs li a {
   display: block;
   font-size: 0.75em;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: black;
   padding: 7px 5px 7px 5px;
}

ul.favs li a:hover {
   color: white;
   background-color: #A32824;
}

.movie_list, .movie_single {
    margin-left: 225px;
    width: 610px;
    border: 1px dotted gray;
}

.movie_list {
   padding-top: 10px;
}

.welcome {
   font-size: 0.8em;
   text-align: justify;
   padding: 10px 10px 20px 10px;
   border-bottom: 1px dotted gray;
}

.movie_list h2, .movie_single h2 {
   font-size: 1.3em;
   padding: 5px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.movie_list ul {
   padding-top: 20px;
}

.movie_list li {
   padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.movie_list h3 a {
   font-size: 1.1em;
   color: #438BC5;
   font-weight: bold;
   display: block;
   margin-top: 0.5em;
   margin-bottom: 0.5em;
   text-decoration: none;
}

.movie_list h3 a:hover {
   text-decoration: underline;
}


.thumbnail {
    width: 178px;
    height: 100px;
}

.movie_list figcaption {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
   padding-left: 20px;
}

.movie_list .description {
   font-size: 0.75em;
   width: 400px;
   text-align: justify;
   padding-right: 10px;
}

.movie_player {
   width: 608px;
   height: 344px;
}

.movie_single h3 {
   font-size: 1.3em;
   padding: 10px;
}

.movie_single p {
   font-size: 0.8em;
   padding: 10px;
}

.movie_single .description {
   font-size: 0.75em;
   min-height: 80px;
   text-align: justify;
}

.actions {
   position: relative;
   height: 37px;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
}

.actions .add_remove {
   position: absolute;
   right: 10px;
}

.actions .add_remove p {
   font-size: 0.75em;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: #999;
}

.actions .add_remove p:hover {
   color: black;
   border-bottom: 3px solid #993300;
}

/* All the sprite images */
.trash-hover, .trash, .delete, .delete-hover, .fav, .fav-hover, .insert, .insert-hover, .arrow, .arrow-hover, .profile-out, .profile-in, .success{
 background: url('../images/sprites.png') no-repeat;
}

.trash-hover{
 background-position: 0 -61px ;
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
}

.trash{
 background-position: 0 0;
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
}

.delete{
 background-position: 0 -130px ;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
}

.delete-hover{
 background-position: -21px -130px ;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
}

.fav{
 background-position: 0 -154px ;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
}

.fav-hover{
 background-position: -21px -154px ;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
}

.insert{
 background-position: 0 -177px ;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
}

.insert-hover{
 background-position: -21px -177px ;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
}

.arrow{
 background-position: -47px -132px ;
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
}

.arrow-hover{
 background-position: -47px -142px ;
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
}

.profile-out{
 background-position: 0 -199px ;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
}

.profile-in{
 background-position: -33px -199px ;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
}

.success{
 background-position: -44px -177px ;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
}
/* End of sprite images */

footer {
    clear: both;
    height: 60px;
    border-top: 1px dotted gray;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted gray;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

footer p {
   line-height: 60px;
   margin-left: 50px;
   font-size: 0.7em;
   font-weight: bold;
}


footer a {
   font-size: inherit;
   color: black;
}

footer a:hover {
   color: #A32824;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="sprites/sprites.css" rel="stylesheet">
        
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
            <script src="scripts/html5shiv-printshiv.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
                             
        <title>Instant Update Database Project by WebinAction.co.uk</title>        
    </head>
    
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Instant Update Database Project</h1>
    </header>

<nav class="navigation">
    <div class="select_users">
            <h2><a href='#'>Alfred the Awful</a></h2>    </div>
    <div class="profile-in"></div>
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    
    <ul class = 'users_menu'><li><a href='#'>Albert Square</a></li><li><a href='#'>Bill Gaits</a></li><li><a href='#'>Gromit </a></li><li><a href='#'>James Olivier</a></li><li><a href='#'>King Beans II</a></li><li><a href='#'>Michael Douglas</a></li><li><a href='#'>Mike Cheeseyman</a></li><li><a href='#'>Mr Movieman</a></li><li><a href='#'>Steven Seagul</a></li><li><a href='#'>Sweeney Toad</a></li><li><a href='#'>The Queen of Sheba</a></li><li><a href='#'>Wallace </a></li><li class='logout'><a href='index.php'>Logout</a></li></ul>    
    <ul class="admin_menu">
        <li><a href="admin.php?page=users">Manage users</a></li>
        <li><a href="admin.php?page=movies">Manage movies</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<nav class="favs_list">
    <h2>Favourites</h2>
    <ul class="favs">
        <li><a href="#">Movie Title</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Movie Title</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Movie Title</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class='trash'></div>            
</nav> <section class="movie_list">
    <h2>Hi, (username will appear here)</h2>
    <p class="welcome">Here are some movies you might like.
    Click on the heart icon to add them to your favourites list.</p>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <figure><a href="#"><img class="thumbnail" alt="Thumbnail"
                    src="images-movies/thumbnail.png"></a>
                <figcaption>
                    <h3><a href="#">Movie Title</a></h3>
                    <div class="description">Movie description</div>
                    <div class="add_remove favourite"></div>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
            <figure><a href="#"><img class="thumbnail" alt="Thumbnail"
                    src="images-movies/thumbnail.png"></a>
                <figcaption>
                    <h3><a href="#">Movie Title</a></h3>
                    <div class="description">Movie description</div>
                    <div class="add_remove add favourite"></div>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
            <figure><a href="#"><img class="thumbnail" alt="Thumbnail"
                    src="images-movies/thumbnail.png"></a>
                <figcaption>
                    <h3><a href="#">Movie Title</a></h3>
                    <div class="description">Movie description</div>
                    <div class="add_remove favourite"></div>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>        <footer>
            <p>Instant update database project by <a href="mailto:learn@webinaction.co.uk">learn@webinaction.co.uk</a></p>
        </footer>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add the `sprites.png` image? We are not able to see the sprites for `profile-in` and `arrow` without it.

Comment: Hi machinehead115,

I am unable to add the image file in my question in way that displays the sprites in the website. How should I do that?

Cloud

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do `position: absolute` similar to how you are position the text, so something like this:

```
.profile-out {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  right: 30px;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Lucas. This solution works, but I will need to calibrate this for both the "profile-in" and "arrow" sprite image. Is there some code that I can use to ensure that the 3 div classes (i.e. select_users, arrow and profile-in) align in a row?

Comment: You can put them in a `<div>` container that is `position: relative`, that should allow you to keep them fairly lined up, or you can utilize floats and use margin to line them up.  They appear to all be different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap them in a `<div>` and set `text-align:center;` to that div.